# How to set locale for just currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

The Rails Guide for [i18n](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) suggests the following to se the `locale` which works great

```
around_action :switch_locale

def switch_locale(&action)
  locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
end
```

With the [rails-i18n](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-i18n/) gem that lets us call [number_to_currency](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) and it does a great job of giving the currency in the proper locale. Is there a way to set locale *just* for `number_to_currency`? Then someone could choose a different language but still have `number_to_currency` in the `en` locale and vice versa.

Comment: Pass in the desired locale to the number_to_currency calls, and use the default current locale for everything else.

Comment: Besides @dbugger's excellent suggestion you do realize that `I18n.with_locale` takes a block? You can call it ANYWHERE in your code and the code in the block/callable will be executed with the given locale. The example from the docs just shows it used in a around_acrion filter to wrap the entire request as thats how its most commonly used.